# FFMPEG: How to remove audio from entire directory

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a novice coder using Terminal on MAC that has installed FFMPEG and attempting to edit an entire directory.

My goal is **to remove all of the audio from all of the videos and output or overwrite the existing files**. I was successful in writing a line of code that inputted and outputted ONE file accurately, however, when I attempted to adapt the code others have posted across the web, the terminal would time-out or error. Attached are a couple of screenshots of what happens for two of the scenarios I thought was sure to work:

Screenshot one:
[image]

Screenshot two:
[image]

Comment: Next time posting code, please copy-paste the code into the editor. Screenshots are hard to read and copy from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code you adapted was intended for `.avi` files, not `.mp4`, so you are trying to replace a string that does not exist.

The following would work:

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -an -c:v copy "${f/%.mp4/-noaudio.mp4}"
done
```